# Get vueRouter version for 3 and / or 4 and above

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-router4

I'd like to log (console.log) the versions of vue / vuex / vuerouter from inside my web app.
I can't get my vuerouter 4# version.
Anybody knows how to do it ?
In version 4.0 we dont have a 'global' vueRouter object, so I can not even try 'vueRouter.version....

I don't want the tipical npm list.... I want to do it from inside de web app.

Any idea ? Thanks-

Comment: Why do you want to do it from inside the web app? This info should be in package.json.

Comment: @cSharp No... Ypu can have a greater version and you don't know...